# Assigning list (of MaskedTextBox) with list of MaskedTextBox controls in the form

Tags: vb.net, maskedtextbox

I tried out the following code to assign the list of `MaskedTextBox` controls in the from to a list `msklist`. But the index value is still 0 even after executing the code I have shown below. I have 30 `MaskedTextBox` controls in my form.

```
Private msklist As New List(Of MaskedTextBox)
Private msk() As MaskedTextBox
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is MaskedTextBox Then
        msklist.Add(ctrl)
    End If
Next

MsgBox(msklist.Count)
ReDim msk(msklist.Count - 1)

msk = msklist.ToArray

    For i = 0 To 29 Step 1
        query = "SELECT * FROM allotment_table WHERE seat=@seat"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seat", seat1(i))
                cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
        con.Open()
        re = cmd.ExecuteReader

        re.Read()
        msk(i).Text = re("regno")
        con.Close()
    Next
```

I was hoping to assign text to the controls' `Text` property using for loop with the array `msk`

I need some suggestions

Comment: A simpler way to do this (assuming you're using a recent version of the framework) would be `For Each ctrl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of MaskedTextBox) ... Next`

Comment: I need to do this in a sequential manner. With the index value I need to do a few more operations like **retreiving data from database** I will update the question

Comment: Have you put a break point on `msklist.Add(ctrl)` and verified it is adding 30 items into the list?

Comment: I tried but it paused for about 4 or 5 times only

Comment: Oh my goodness, why are you executing the same query 30 times?

Comment: yup I don't know a better way of doing this

Comment: I have updated the code again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Private msklist As New List(Of MaskedTextBox)

' Loop through all controls in form
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Panel Then
        ' Loop through each of the controls in the Panel
        For Each panelCtrl As Control In ctrl.Controls
            If TypeOf panelCtrl Is MaskedTextBox Then
                msklist.Add(panelCtrl)
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

MsgBox(msklist.Count)

' Get the text value once and apply it to each text box
query = "SELECT * FROM allotment_table"
cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
con.Open()
re = cmd.ExecuteReader
re.Read()
Dim textValue As String = re("regno")
con.Close()

' Loop through the list of masked text boxes and apply the text value to each
For Each mskTextBox As MaskedTextBox In msklist
    mskTextBox.Text = textValue
Next
```

Comment: No errors but the vales are not getting assigned to the controls **still the list size is 0**

Comment: Okay, can you debug the line `msklist.Add(ctrl)`, when it actually hits, step one line past and see if the count of the list increases by one or not?

Comment: I placed a brakepoint but it didn't pause. Not even once and still 0

Comment: Are you positive that you have `MaskedTextBox` controls on this form? Also, try explicitly declaring your `ctrl` value as a `Control`, see updated answer.

Comment: I have MaskedTextBoxes but they are placed in a panel will that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, that makes a big difference, you need to loop through the controls inside the `Panel`, I updated the answer and assumed the name of your panel was `Panel1`, change it if the name is different. See updated answer.

Comment: Finally it works. How can I check five more panels in the same for loop

Comment: You can do it with nested loops, the outer loop will loop through all the controls of the form, looking for panels, and the inner loop will loop through all of the controls of the panel, looking for masked text boxes. See updated answer.

Comment: the list is jumbled. How can i sort the list of maskedtextbox

Comment: @Dineshbabu - ask a new question, stating you now want to sort the list and specify how you want the list sorted.